# How to add positional parameter with default value in GetX Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I'm trying to add a positional parameter with default value with [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get) in Flutter but I got an error.

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class MainParentModel {
  int id;
  String name;
  RxBool isSelected;

  MainParentModel(this.id, this.name, {this.isSelected = false.obs});
}
```

Error: *The default value of an optional parameter must be constant.dartnon_constant_default_value*

How can I add this default value?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`.obs` is a getter that returns an `Rx<T>` of whatever type you add it to. But it's not a constant value so that won't work. You'll notice that if you just use a regular `bool` and remove `.obs` the error goes away.

If it has to be type `RxBool`, then I'm pretty sure your only option is making it required and passing in `false.obs` whenever you create a new `MainParentModel`.

```
MainParentModel(this.id, this.name, {required this.isSelected});
```

Then a new instance would look like this.

```
final model = MainParentModel(1, 'Bob', isSelected: false.obs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is creating reactive objects where you'll need, I never use classes with reactive variables, for example:

```
class MainParentModel {
  int id;
  String name;
  bool isSelected;

  MainParentModel(this.id, this.name, {this.isSelected = false});
}
```

In the controller:

```
Rx<MainParentModel> mainParentModel = MainParentModel().obs;
```

if you need to rebuild the page when changing isSelected variable:

```
mainParentModel.update((model){

 model.isSelected = true;

});
```

or

```
mainParentModel.refresh();
```

This will trigger rebuild all Obx that you use mainParentModel.value.?